# Python: unable to pass string values read from file through `for` loop

Tags: python, string, loops

I'm trying to return the median of all the values in a dataframe whose rows also contain each one of a list of string values. I can successfully make it work manually one at a time like this:

```
line = "History"
df_q = df_genre['roi'].loc[df_genre['genre'] == line].median()
print(line, df_q)
```

But when I try to automate the process by reading in the string values through an `if` loop, I get `nan` results instead of the median values. Here's my code:

```
with open('genres_unique') as i:
    for line in i:
        df_line = df_genre['roi'].loc[df_genre['genre'] == line].median()
        print(line, df_line)
```

Comment: Will you be able to add context to your question by adding output for the first code block, and what is in `genres_unique` and expected output for the second code block?

Comment: But for something upfront that might seem wrong is the `for line in i:`, when it should be `for line in i.readlines():`. `for line in i` will attempt to iterate `i`, which is a file object (non-iterable, hence NaN). You will need to get the lines out of the file, then iterate those lines (`i.readlines()`)

Comment: @TimothyWong: no, that's what iterating directly over a file is equivalent to.  Likely problem is that the lines (except maybe the last one) will end with a newline character, which won't match the dataframe values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@jasonharper was correct: I needed to strip the newline character from my text file. Here's the correct code using `rstrip`:

```
with open('genres/genres_unique') as i:
    for line in i:
        newline = line.rstrip()
        df_line = df_genre['roi'].loc[df_genre['genre'] == newline].median()
        print(line, df_line)
```